# Integrate an existing Symfony2 application with Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, symfony, content-management-system, drupal-7, integration

The future development of my symfony2 project
( which is actually more or less a static website with an authentification system )
 would be to provide authentified users a CMS to easily edit text and images / import files / create pages / give acces to their pages as the website grows and evolves.
I have been thinking implementing my project with Drupal would be way forward .

how can i proceed ?
Is doing the reverse better?
what are other options?

Comment: If you can, it could be worth waiting for drupal 8: http://symfony.com/blog/symfony2-meets-drupal-8

Comment: or maybe take a look at [CMF](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by 'the reverse', but there is a [Symfony module](http://drupal.org/project/symfony) available for D7. I would suggest setting up a Drupal test bed and seeing about integrating your site into drupal.

It is my understanding that Symfony2 has gone into core in D8, but D8 is probably a long way from initial release.